# The difference of a variable has a unit root, but the variable itself doesn't

Tags: time-series, unit-root, ardl

I am trying to build an ARDL model with the six following variables: `lnNO2`,`lnP`,`lnGDP`,`lnEI`,`lnU` and `lnU2` (one response and five dependent variables). The variables I am using are shown below:
[image]

One of the preconditions of an ARDL is that all the variables are either I(0) or I(1). But when I conduct the Zivot-Andrews unit root test on the variables, I obtain strange results: some variables are stationary at levels but not stationary at differences, and some variables are not stationary at levels but are indeed stationary at differences. The variable below is an example:

```
> summary(ur.za(df$lnU, model = "trend")) # No Unit Root

################################ 
# Zivot-Andrews Unit Root Test # 
################################ 


Call:
lm(formula = testmat)

Residuals:
       Min         1Q     Median         3Q        Max 
-0.0041138 -0.0007737  0.0001303  0.0009452  0.0052163 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.6331285  0.1229855   5.148 7.84e-06 ***
y.l1         0.8258369  0.0349727  23.614  < 2e-16 ***
trend        0.0028385  0.0006549   4.334 9.95e-05 ***
dt          -0.0014855  0.0003439  -4.319 0.000104 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.002034 on 39 degrees of freedom
  (1 observation deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.9998,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9998 
F-statistic: 7.967e+04 on 3 and 39 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16


Teststatistic: -4.98 
Critical values: 0.01= -4.93 0.05= -4.42 0.1= -4.11 

Potential break point at position: 18 

> summary(ur.za(diff(df$lnU), model = "trend")) # Unit Root

################################ 
# Zivot-Andrews Unit Root Test # 
################################ 


Call:
lm(formula = testmat)

Residuals:
       Min         1Q     Median         3Q        Max 
-0.0052449 -0.0002637 -0.0000411  0.0004080  0.0031726 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  4.691e-03  1.978e-03   2.372   0.0229 *  
y.l1         7.811e-01  8.719e-02   8.958 6.63e-11 ***
trend       -1.196e-04  4.892e-05  -2.444   0.0193 *  
dt           1.944e-04  7.966e-05   2.440   0.0194 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.001116 on 38 degrees of freedom
  (1 observation deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.9445,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9402 
F-statistic: 215.8 on 3 and 38 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16


Teststatistic: -2.511 
Critical values: 0.01= -4.93 0.05= -4.42 0.1= -4.11 

Potential break point at position: 28
```

As you can clearly see, the variable `lnU` has no unit root (Test Statistic lower that Critical Values), while the variable `diff(lnU)` does have a unit root (Test statistic higher than Critical Value). This situation only occurs for the variables `lnU` and `lnU2`, the other variables are all both level-stationary and difference-stationary.

Question: Will the ARDL model built with those variables be valid, since all the variables are either I(0) or I(1)? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Hi: Based on the plots most of your variables have some kind of trend. A trend can be due to a time trend or a non-stationary mean. If it's a time trend, then there is a standard way to get rid of it and your resulting series is termed "trend-stationary" (TS). A series with a  non-stationary mean can sometimes be differenced so that it becomes stationary. In this case, the series is called difference stationary (DS). The difficult thing is determining whether a series trend-stationary or difference stationary.

Comment: A well known ( but old ) paper that chooses between these two types of stationarity for various series is by "nelson and plosser" if you can get that paper, it may show you how to check for difference stationarity versus trend stationarity. As it stands, you shouldn't test for statonarity until you decide whether your various series are DS or TS.

Comment: Here's the paper. It was quite famous at the time and is still referenced quite a bit.https://hedibert.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/nelson-plosser-1982.pdf. I hope it helps. That's the first step you should take: figure out if your series are difference stationary or trend stationary.

Comment: @mlofton, to add to a good point of yours, it may be more precise to use the term *deterministic time trend* instead of *time trend* (as opposed to *stochastic trend*, i.e. a unit root process). *Nonstationary mean* covers also the case of deterministic time trends, so the former term can be confusing, too. *Stochastic trend* could be a better alternative, though it is less general (excludes breaks and such).

Comment: Hi Richard: You make excellent points. The terminology can be quite confusing and to add confusion, I was sloppy.  I like deterministic time trend. Yes, "non-stationary mean" was an awful choice. I should have been more specific and either used stochastic trend  or tried to give an example. Hopefully, Nelson and Plosser give some examples. I've read that paper a few times but I can't remember my take on it ?. Some time-series econometrics text might talk about DS versus TS but I can't think of one at the moment. Maybe Hayashi ? I don't have any textbooks at my fingertips that I can check.

Comment: Said: One other thing you can do is google for either "difference stationary" or "trend stationary". Whatever you find will discuss both because they are two ways that a series can be non-stationary. There are other ways also but these two kind of rival each other because they are both processes where the mean is changing . The method one then uses to "de-trend" the series will depend on whether the series is trend or difference stationary.